# SQL Server 2008 OLE DB CONNECTION FAILS FROM OUTSIDE

Tags: connection, oledb, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have a working SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installed on a Windows 2008 server on a cloud machine. All type of connections (ado.net, nhibernate etc.) from several client applications works fine except the OLEDB one. SQL Native Client also works fine.

When I tried to connect from the server locally and as a data source write the instance name, everything was OK. But from outside, I had the problem or also if I write wan ip or dns I had the problem also from local.

```
-- works perfect from everywhere
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Data Source=mntek.no-ip.org;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx; 

-- does not work from anywhere
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=mntek.no-ip.org;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;

-- works only from local
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=flz001\sqlexpress;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;
```

> Error: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()).Invalid
>   connection.

```
-- works perfect with ado.net
Data Source=mntek.no-ip.org;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx
```

Some other client applications (not mine) was written with oledb connection so I need them to connect the db with oledb provider.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Mert

Comment: Did you try using IP instead of name? Also try adding `;Network=DBMSSOCN` to the connection string? I'm also confused - is this a named instance (`\sqlexpress`) or a default instance? Your connection strings are contradicting each other.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I also tried IP and adding Network property but still does not work. In the Properties - Name writes FLZ001\SQLEXPRESS in management studio so I guess its a named instance (installed by customer). I tried every possibility for connection string so they may be contradict each other.

Answer (score 6):

It has been a while since this was asked, but I am currently working through an issue related to OLE DB and SQL Server that sounds possibly related.

I found that, even though the server was using the default port (1433), I still had to explicitly specify it in the UDL connection string like this:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=USER;Data Source=IP,1433
```

I've asked why that might be necessary here:
[Why might SQL Server 2008 OLE DB UDL require port 1433 explicitly specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491347/why-might-sql-server-2008-ole-db-udl-require-port-1433-explicitly-specified)

Maybe try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Why downvote?  Explicitly adding a port to the connection string could be a solution.

Comment: This solved the problem for me when failing to connect to external SQL Server DB from VBA. Thank you!