# Connect to SQL using OleDbConnection failing

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I'm connecting to a remote SQL database using the OleDbConnection but it's failing.

```
var connection = new OleDbConnection
{
    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=MyRemoteIPAddress;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=sa;Password=MyPassword"
};

try
{
    connection.Open();
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

The error I am getting is : [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()).]Invalid connection.

However if I connect using SqlConnection, it connects ok.

```
var testConnection = new SqlConnection
{
    ConnectionString = "server=MyIPAddress;database=MYDatabase;user id=MyUser;pwd=MyPassword"
};

try
{
    testConnection.Open();
    testConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Why can i connect via SqlConnection and not OleDbConnection?

Comment: Is your environment clustered by chance? If so, you may need to explicitly specify the port, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491347/why-might-sql-server-2008-ole-db-udl-require-port-1433-explicitly-specified

Comment: Its not clustered, Just a box with SQL installed (with pretty much a standard setup)

Comment: offtopic: have you noticed that http://www.connectionstrings.com/ has a connection error? :)

Comment: There may be different reasons for this exception. we need more details to help you solve it. What version of sql server? does your server use a named instance? read [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/82007/how-do-i-get-this-sql-server-odbc-connection-working) and [there](https://www.teamdotnetnuke.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/235/20/dbnetlibconnectionopen-invalid-instanceinvalid-connection-error-when-binding-mssql-database-with-plesk-10)

Comment: try "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=MyRemoteIPAddress;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=sa;Password=MyPassword;Data Source=IP,1433"

Answer (score 1):

The environment is not clustered but explicitly specifying the port fixed the issue.

This worked :

"Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=MyRemoteIPAddress,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=sa;Password=MyPassword"

Answer (score 0):

Try using a server side code which does all the required functions. so that your application does not directly talk with the remote database. Ping me for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

you should specify the port `1433` when using OLEDB

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=MyRemoteIPAddress,1433;Initial 
Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=sa;Password=MyPassword;
```